# OCR on strikeout text using pytesseract and opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have images where the text is striken-out by the printing errors, what are the preprocessing methods that can be utilised in order to do the OCR on those images.

Few examples are as follows.

[image: so img 1]

and

[image: so img 2]

`Tesseract-ocr` is unable to detect  those numbers.

Comment: https://magda.space/removing-circles-lines-patterns-part-1/ look for something thats remove the lines first ?